# PHPMAILER don't add a inline image with $mail->AddEmbeddedImage

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I use phpmailer to send emails to users. All works perfectly except one

```
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $mailSubject;
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('logo_email.jpg', 'logo', 'logo_email.jpg');
$mail->Body = $mailBody."\n
    <p>This is a test picture: <img src='cid:logo' /></p>\n";
$mail->AltBody = $mailSubject;
```

this is the last part of my code. When I saw the email no image is load. In particular, if I see the original email on the email client I saw this:

```
        <p>This is a test picture: <img src="cid:logo"></p>
```

cid:logo was not replaced in the email body. I tried with absolute path and with the image in the same directory by no change. I read a lot of post in StackOverflow and in other forums but I do not find any solutions

Comment: did you try it in different browsers ?

Comment: yes sure... different browser, differents client email, different computers

Answer (score 0):

Make sure **logo_email.jpg** is in correct path OR give like param as a relative path as below.

`$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('./logo_email.jpg', 'logo', 'logo_email.jpg');`